# iPhone - is @2x valid for UIWebView?

Tags: iphone

I have this UIWebView on my app that shows a local html file. Do the images on that web view follow the @2x rule? I mean, if I build both, the regular and the @2x images will the webview load the retina ones for the iPhone 4?

remember that the images are being loaded by the HTML tag , not by any UIImage method.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jonathon Grynspan is correct. I recommend reading Aral Balkan's tutorial on the topic. This was what I read when I implemented @2x graphics for a recent mobile site:

[How to make your web content look stunning on the iPhone 4’s new Retina display](http://aralbalkan.com/3331)

Answer (score 7):

Nope. It's not too hard to roll your own though, as WebKit supports this CSS rule:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /* this is a retina display device */
}
```

You can also use the `-webkit-background-size` and the usual `width` and `height` selectors to ensure the images display at the correct physical size.

Answer (score 1):

No, I just tried an experiment and the UIWebView did not pick up the @2x image.

Comment: You might want to post the experiment.

Comment: The experiment was precisely what the OP asked about: Created a sample project, put in a UIWebView, put in an image tag to a test image, created a @2x version of the image, ran the project on a retina device, and the non-@2x version of the image showed up.   Why downvote, my answer is complete and correct!   Not as good as the other ones since I didn't say how to work around it, so vote those up instead, but downvoting a correct answer?   Really...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer to a similar question is interesting [UIWebView and iPhone 4 retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724058/uiwebview-and-iphone-4-retina-display/7741453#7741453). It uses Javascript to load scaled images and set the width properly.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i.m.o is to always load a retina image, and set the size to 50% for the image. It will look good on retina and non-retina displays. Should be sufficient.